# Multiplas querys com php

Tags: php, query, mysqli

ola a todos gostaria de saber como faço para rodar duas querys ao mesmo tempo no php a situação eo seguinte pretendo fazer um insert e retornar a chave auto_increment estou fazendo o seguinte

```
$query = "INSERT INTO usuario(cd_usuario,nome_usuario)VALUES ('0000','Fabricio')ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE nome_usuario = 'Fabricio Silva';SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS ID";
$query = mysqli_multi_query($conexao,$query);//Ate aqui funciona
$query = mysqli_store_result($query);
$query = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```

Neste caso nao vai ativar o ON DUPLI.... pq estou mandando gerar nova chave, preciso recuperar o id do usuario para atribuir uma imagem a ele

Comment: Você precisa chamar o `mysqli_next_result()` primeiro.

Comment: poderia exemplificar e explicar para que serveria ?

Comment: Não é mais simples usar [mysqli_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) para pegar o id do registro inserido?

Comment: nao conhecia o comando vo da uma olhada

Comment: uaaau funcionou perfeitamento com o codigo muiito simples a ultima duvida e se nao corre o risco de ele pegar uma id de outra seção ou seja no momento que eu pegar a id do banco poderia ser de outro cadastro

Comment: Não tem esse problema.

Comment: Isso se chama "race condition", mas o MySQL irá pegar o ultimo id da conexão atual e não do último do banco quando chamar a função, logo não tem o problema. Bem, na verdade existe uma condição especifica para isso ocorrer, **que não é o seu caso**. Isto ocorre _somente_ se estiver utilizando replicas (Master - Master em "Active-Active Mode"), pode ocorrer colisão dos `AUTO_INCREMENT` entre os bancos, mas isso é um problema do MySQL, que é "previsível" nesse tipo de replica. Nestes caso  terá que usar o `auto_increment_increment` e o `auto_increment_offset`.